# Quarkus: custom rest extension deployment

Tags: resteasy, quarkus

I'm new to Quarkus, I wrote an extension that provides a rest API, let's call it `/myapi`.

```java
@Path("/myapi")
public class MyApi {

  @Inject
  private ServiceInterface someService; //provided by the app that uses the extension

  @POST
  public MyResponse processMessage(MyMessage message) {
    return someService.processMessage(message);
  }

}
```

The idea is that the extensions would provide the *rest resources* needed by the application(s) and the application provides the business logic.

So I created a Quarkus project that uses that extension and provides a bean that implements `ServiceInterface` with the business logic.

But, when I start the app, the endpoint `/myapi` is not created, and when I call it, it returns a `404`.

The question is: how can I make the *rest resource* defined in the extension visible to the application that uses it?

Answer (score 1):

I finally came up with this solution:

```java
 @BuildStep
  void addDominoApi(BuildProducer<AdditionalBeanBuildItem> additionalBeans) {
    additionalBeans.produce(AdditionalBeanBuildItem.unremovableOf(MyApi.class));
  }
```

Adding `MyApi` to the *additional beans*

Comment: I tried this suggestion, but it didn't work for me. Turned out I didn't have a `META-INF/beans.xml` in the `runtime` part of my extension. Adding that file (it can be empty apart from the `<beans>` root element) will make the beans of your extension discoverable.