# How to create quarkus custom extension for access resource

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-extension

I tried the below code to access the  "GreetingResource" using custom extension, but not able to access. sample code:

```java
@BuildStep
void build(BuildProducer<AdditionalBeanBuildItem> additionalBeans) {
    additionalBeans.produce(
        AdditionalBeanBuildItem.unremovableOf(GreetingResource.class)
    );
}
```

Comment: We will need a lot more information about what you are trying to do if we are to help

Comment: @geoand my requirement is create a generic end point, there we are doing some business logic. this extension need to add as dependency in other modules.

Comment: What extensions are you using?

Comment: i am creating a custom extension for this  generic end point.I tried the solution as per the below link :
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65033775/quarkus-custom-rest-extension-deployment
but not worked for me

Comment: Probably a better example to follow is https://quarkus.io/guides/building-my-first-extension. I think you have some of that code in your extension, judging from the class names, but I can't tell how much of it. 

Things like logs and what error code you see on the new custom endpoint would be helpful.

Comment: @HollyCummins, actually I created the custom extension from above link (that you mentioned) only. But instead of  :
ServletBuildItem createServlet() build step
 I used 
void build (BuildProducer<AdditionalBeanBuildItem> additionalBeans)  buildstep 
for getting the rest endpoint.

Comment: Got it. And have you confirmed that if you run your `GreetingResource` as a normal application, rather than as an extension, you get the REST endpoint you want?

Comment: Currently I have a requirement that one rest endpoint and its business logic need to add as library to some projects, so that i created the endpoint in custom extension.

Comment: Got one solution and it  worked for me :
   @BuildStep
    ReflectiveClassBuildItem reflectiveClass() {
          return ReflectiveClassBuildItem.builder(GreetingResource.class).build();
    }